# What is current phase of starting capacitor in single phase motor

Tags: induction-motor

Is that staring circuit current lag or leading?
Some maker's document said,
If capacitance is higer, starting torque and current will be higher.
It means that the current is leading (capacitive) in the starting winding circuit.
But, I saw some waveform is lag than voltage on the internet.

If it is lag, higher capacitance will make more inductive.(=lower current and torque)

What is the current type(lag or leading) in the starting winding with capacitor in series.

Answer (score 1):

What is important is not the phase of the current compared to the voltage but the phase of the start winding current compared to the main winding current. It is the difference in phase between these currents and hence the magnetic fields that they create that results in a rotating magnetic field.

A you would expect a capacitor in the start winding creates current phase lead compared to the current in the main winding.

The windings are inductive so they will cause a current lag relative to the voltage,

Comment: I think so. But, motor maker said, the bigger  capacitor(uF), the bigger current and torque. I doesn't make sense then. If inductive current, it will be opposite.